# Node.js puppeteer - Transforming fetched href string

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. ... now I want to transform one of my outputs. Instead of getting a href like this:

Console:

```
myURL/data/1344888/156999-18-1605-index.html
```

The desired output should have this structure:

```
myURL/data/1344888/156999181605/156999-18-1605.txt
```

As you can see ... the first part is identical:

```
myURL/data/1344888/
```

... the middle part should have no hyphen and is the first part of the last part:

```
                  /156999181605/
```

... and in the last part ... the -index.html should be replaced by .txt

```
                               /156999-18-1605.txt
```

That's how I fetch the original href:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

(async function main() {
  try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('myURL', {waitUntil: 'load'});

    const table = await page.waitForSelector('#formDiv > div > table');

    const link = await page.$('#formDiv > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3) > a');
    const linkHref = await page.evaluate( link => link.href, link );

    console.log(linkHref);      

    ...


  } catch (e) {
    console.log('our error', e);
  }

})();
```

How could this be done?

Console:

```
myURL/data/1344888/156999-18-1605-index.html
```

Desired output should:

```
myURL/data/1344888/156999181605/156999-18-1605.txt
```

Comment: With a regexp. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution to convert your original URL into the format you desire:

```
const original_url = 'myURL/data/1344888/156999-18-1605-index.html';
const modified_url = original_url.replace( /(\d+-\d+-\d+-index.html)/, match => match.replace( /\D/g, '' ) + '/' + match.replace( '-index.html', '.txt' ) );

console.log( original_url ); // myURL/data/1344888/156999-18-1605-index.html
console.log( modified_url ); // myURL/data/1344888/156999181605/156999-18-1605.txt
```